# Connecting to Bluetooth LE

Tags: android, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

My Bluetooth gatt connectivity was working fine but all of a sudden after i pass the following line:

```
mConnectedGATT = device.connectGatt(com.wicom.bluetoothgatt.MainActivity.this, true, mGattCallback);
```

the OnConnectionStateChanged event is called 6,7 times does that mean there is a problem with the physical device?

I am adding logcat snapshot for reference[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you connect with autoConnect set to true, or call gatt.connect(), it will automatically reconnect to the device if the connection is dropped, either by lost connection or because the peripheral actively disconnected.